# IRepository<> and SOA together

Tags: design-patterns, soa

i need some helps on using IRepository<> pattern and SOA together.

i'm developing an accounting application which includes very complex business logics. currently i'm using the IRepository as a DAL which only do the basic CRUD + things like  providing an IQueryable interface, some caching features and so on.

on top of it, i have a BusinessLogic layer which play the role of Service or Facade layer (are they the same thing?). all of the application logics encapsulated here as methods which will be used by Presentation layer.

as i said all basic CRUD are placed in repositories but further that take place in BusinessLogic, for example we may only have these basic methods in our Account repository :

```
public class AccountRepository
{
    public IList<Accounts> GetAll()
    {
        ...
    }

    public Accounts Get(int id)
    {
        ...
    }

    public IList<Accounts Where(Func<Accounts,bool> criteria)
    {
        ...
    }

    public Accounts Add(Accounts item)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

but to get an account with a specific number we would have a service like this :

```
public class AccountService
{
    AccountRepository repos;

    public Accounts FindByNumber(int AccountNumber)
    {
        return repos.Where(o=>o.AccountNumber == AccountNumber).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

AccountService also could have a CreateAccount() method which add multiple entities (an account, an owner and ...) by using entities repository and in a single transaction.

now i want to know am i using them in a right way ? or did i miss some points ?

Comment: I use this all the time, have a look at this article esp. the part on gateways.
[SOA Design Pattern](http://hubpages.com/_1k9ore6as3b3m/hub/SOA-Design-Pattern-WCF)

Comment: Thanks a lot, what do you do for managing transactions ? i mean in which layer do you handle them ? (i think of Engine layer) and how do you implement them in this architect ?

Answer (score 0):

@sos00 asked "what do you do for managing transactions ? i mean in which layer do you handle them ? (i think of Engine layer) and how do you implement them in this architect"

In a SOA, you can never be entirely certain of your call chain, as the services you write today will be orchestrated in a different way tomorrow.

I follow this heuristic; on the boundary of every service I will join an ambient transaction if it is passed to me and enlist into that transaction, if no ambient transaction is present I will become the root of a new transaction. This way I am certain that any work that I need to do is transaction and will be passed on to other components I pull into my orchestration.

See this article: [Building Integrity into SOA](http://hubpages.com/hub/Achieving-Non-Functional-Requirements-for-a-Service-Oriented-Software-Platform-Integrity)